# Upload a Directory on Django Project

Tags: jquery, python, django, html, upload

I was wondering whether I can upload a ***directory*** instead of a file to a ***Django*** application related path, i.e on `static/logs/` directory of a Django project?

I have seen that it's possible to "*upload*" a directory via **HTML5** but I can't find a good tutorial to start working on it, everything is about a single or multiple file uploads.